# parsing and generating code with preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm experimenting with roslyn, parsing and generating c# code. I'm trying to figure out how the `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText` method handles preprocessor symbols.

Here is my test method. It takes in some C# code as a string, extracts the `using` statements and returns a new string with those `using` statements, taking into account preprocessor directives.

```
private static string Process(string input, string[] preprocessorSymbols)
{
    var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithPreprocessorSymbols(preprocessorSymbols);
    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(input, options);
    var compilationUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)syntaxTree.GetRoot();
    var usings = compilationUnit.Usings.ToArray();
    var cs = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
            .AddUsings(usings)
            .NormalizeWhitespace();
    var result = cs.ToString();
    return result;
}
```

When feeding this method with the following input, it works as expected:

```
var input = "using MyUsing1;\r\nusing MyUsing2;";
string result = Process(input, new[] { "" });
Assert.AreEqual("using MyUsing1;\r\nusing MyUsing2;", result);
```

When adding a preprocessor directive, but not passing said directive to the parser, the result is still as expected (conditional `using` statement is stripped):

```
var input =
    "using MyUsing1;\r\n" +
    "#if CONDITIONAL\r\n" +
    "using MyUsing2;\r\n" +
    "#endif";
string result = Process(input, new[] { "" });
Assert.AreEqual("using MyUsing1;", result);
```

However, when adding the `CONDITIONAL` preprocessor directive to the `CSharpParseOptions`, I get a strange result

```
var input = 
    "using MyUsing1;\r\n" +
    "#if CONDITIONAL\r\n" +
    "using MyUsing2;\r\n" +
    "#endif";
string result = Process(input, new[] { "CONDITIONAL" });
Assert.AreEqual("using MyUsing1;\r\nusing MyUsing2;", result); // fails??
```

The actual returnvalue is `"using MyUsing1;\r\n#if CONDITIONAL\r\nusing MyUsing2;"`. The `#if CONDITIONAL` part is retained, and `#endif` is removed.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net), among other things it can show the syntax tree of the script.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to understand this behavior, I added another test case to consider:

```
var input =
    "using MyUsing1;\r\n" +
    "#if CONDITIONAL\r\n" +
    "using MyUsing2;\r\n" +
    "#endif" +
    "using MyUsing3;\r\n";
string result = Process(input, new[] { "CONDITIONAL" });
```

And in this case, both the `#if` and the `#endif` are preserved.

If you break in the debugger and look at the `usings` array, it appears that each `UsingDirectiveSyntax` knows both the minimal range of characters for the `using` statement (`Span`) and a "wider" range of characters from the original stream (`FullSpan`) which includes things like, in this case, the `#if` directive.

Digging a little deeper, the docs refer to preceding code like the preproc directive as "leading trivia", and it is attached to the using node as a child.

Interestingly, if you pass `.AddUsings()` just one of the using directives, it seems to omit the leading trivia; but if you give it an array of multiple `UsingDirectiveSyntax`s, then for each except the first, it includes the leading trivia.  (That's probably not exactly right; I'm working from black-box observations only.)

I'm not going to pretend to understand the reasoning for that behavior.  The upshot is that many bits of code that look ok - like your example - will produce troubling output.  (If you pass in `new[] {usings[0], usings[2], usings[1]}` you get even worse-looking output, with the `#endif` before the `#if`.  But... you know... I guess why would you do that?)

So if you want to use these tools to generate source code to be fed back into a full build pipeline, you could see this as a bug (or at least, a weird behavior that could easily be a source of bugs).  If there's intended usage that would keep you clear of this, I can't find straightforward documentation of it.  In this case, you could remove the trivia from the `usings` before adding them to the output; but in other cases, that might drop something you want to preserve I would think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the mean time, by re-reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/work-with-syntax#syntax-trivia), it turns out that directives are 'trivia' and always associated with the *next* line. Strange for this use case, but works as designed I suppose...